# How do I vary page presentation without a sprawling loginview monstrosity in webforms?

Tags: asp.net, view, webforms, loginview

Currently, I have a page that has a table that shows a varying level of information depending upon the logged in status of the requester. It is set up as a table with repeaters pulling from a data source.

Some examples of things that are different:

- The Date of Birth column gives the exact DOB for those with a certain role, and the month of their birth for other users.
- Last names are a hyperlink for those in a certain role, and just a regular literal for everyone else.
- There is also an extra column in a table for those with a certain role.

Currently, I essentially have the entire page duplicated with minor tweaks inside the loginview control. This seems like a poor way to do business, but I'm not really sure of a cleaner way to do it with webforms. With MVC and Razor (which I am less experienced with), it seems like it would be fairly trivial to tweak the output with some conditionals in the view but it seems less intuitive in webforms.

Is there a better way to do this in webforms?

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar implementations using a repeater, and have had success with the following approach:

Use the decorator pattern to add "display directives" to the object you'll bind to the repeater.  In your example, I might add bool flags for ShowFullDob, ShowLastNameAsLink, and ShowColumnX (for your optional column).

When you retrieve your data to be displayed, convert the model objects to your new decorated model objects, and set the bool flags as appropriate for the current request.

This is the part that's a little counter-intuitive: in your repeater's ItemTemplate, render **ALL** the data, but use your bool flags to set the Visible attribute (see code sample below).

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" Visible='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShowFullDob") %>'>construct full DOB here</td>
    <td runat="server" Visible='<%# !((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShowFullDob")) %>'>construct just the birth month/year here</td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Perhaps other SO'ers can suggest more elegant ways of implementing conditional elements within a repeater - if so, I'd love to hear them!  However, even though it's a little ugly and heavy-handed, it gets the job done.